# Iterating over over dynamically created array

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to iterate over an array which contains names of other arrays. My goal is to be able to access each value of each dynamically created array.

This is my loop where I iterate over the $REQUIRED_PARAMS passed from command line

```
for param in "${REQUIRED_PARAMS[@]}"
do
  create_param_array ${param} "${path_to_txt_reports}/${report}"
  echo "${WBC[@]}"
  echo "${!param}"
done
```

This is the function create_param_array, basically the function parse  a file get, get some values and create an array which has the same name as the param

```
################################################
# Function: create_param_array
# Inputs : $1 - param
#          $2 - full relative path to pdf report
# Outputs: array of parameters values
#################################################
create_param_array () {
  path=$2
   case $1 in
     WBC)
       WBC=($(get_param_values $1 $2))
       verbose_print WBC ${WBC[@]}
     ;;
....
```

So far so good, the problem is I need to access the values but I don't know name of the created array so I can't do

```
echo "${WBC[@]}"
```

which prints out all values

```
15.7 11.6 15.8
```

I tried

```
echo "${!param}"
echo "${!param[@]}"
```

but obviously param is not the array so I'm getting

```
15.7
0
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the array name together with the `[@]` in the variable you use in the indirection:

```
#! /bin/bash
WBC=(15.7 11.6 15.8)
p='WBC[@]'
echo "${!p}"
```